# Counting inside a single column for different results

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to write a somewhat complex MySQL query that will count the different items listed in one column as it relates to other criteria.

Currently, the only items in the column are: MC, SR, MP and EV.

This code does work, but my question is, is there a better and more efficient way of doing this? Also, what about a new item being added to the column?

```
$sql = "Select ps.id, ps.primary_skill, 
count(*) 
(select COUNT(*)
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.itemType = 'MC') as mc_count,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.itemType = 'SR') as sr_count,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.itemType = 'MP') as mp_count,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.itemType = 'EV') as ev_count,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.dok = '1') as dok1,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.dok = '2') as dok2,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.dok = '3') as dok3,
(select COUNT(*) 
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
and i.dok = '4') as dok4
FROM primary_skills ps
where grade =  '$pl' and subject='$subject'
";
```

Comment: could you provide result table you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with uses loops:

```
$sql = "Select ps.id, ps.primary_skill ";
foreach ($iTypes as $type){
    $sql .=", (select COUNT(*)
    from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm 
    where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
    and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
    and i.itemType = '$type') as " . strtolower($type) . "_count ";
}
$sql .= "FROM primary_skills ps
where grade =  '$pl' and subject='$subject'";
```

Thank you for all of the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
Select ps.id, ps.primary_skill, count(*), 
       CASE i.itemType = 'MC' THEN COUNT(*) END AS as mc_count,
       CASE i.itemType = 'SR' THEN COUNT(*) END AS as sr_count,
       CASE i.itemType = 'MP' THEN COUNT(*) END AS as mp_count,
       CASE i.itemType = 'EV' THEN COUNT(*) END AS as ev_count,
       CASE i.dok = '1' THEN COUNT(*) END,
       CASE i.dok = '2' THEN COUNT(*) END,
       CASE i.dok = '3' THEN COUNT(*) END,
       CASE i.dok = '4' THEN COUNT(*) END
from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm
where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id FROM 
and grade =  '$pl' 
and subject='$subject'
```

I think this is the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
select i.itemType, count(*)
  from items i, item_primary_skill_map ipsm, primary_skills ps
 where i.id = ipsm.item_id 
   and ipsm.skill_id = ps.id 
   and ps.grade      = '$pl' 
   and ps.subject    = '$subject'      
 group by i.itemType;
```

the difference is that this query returns 1 row per unique value rather than 1 column in your query. for i.dok your would need to do the same.